# Multiple domains but one report in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, reporting

I'd like to generate a report for a dozen or so websites with different domains.

Example:

- `myfirstsite.com`
- `acoolsite.com`
- `brandsite.com`
- etc.

I am obviously able to generate reports for each URL, but how can I generate a master report using Google Analytics that summarizes all the traffic from all the websites?

Answer (score 2):

Google has a method to track across multiple domains and sub-domains

**Tracking Across Multiple Domains and Sub-domains**
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

> In this scenario, you might want to track two unique domains and one
>   sub-domain. For example, suppose you have an online store and you also
>   want to track visitor and campaign data to your blog.

With this you can create reports with combined domains.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer to me. You might add that using these two calls is essentially what makes the difference: `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'my-example-blogsite.com']);` and `_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);`, both before the actual `_trackPage` call is pushed.

Answer (score 1):

The only suggestion that I could think would work would be to place identical tracking codes across all your sites and this would amalgamate all the data from the sites. This could be added in as a second tracking number so you do not lose your current tracking system.

You would then be able to generate one report for the combined data for your sites or you could create filters, one for each site (setting 'Domain'), and apply the filters to different sections of a custom reports.

This would only work for future data and would require some time to set up, however after this point it would streamline the process and allow you to see the data in one place. Depending what data you wished to view you could set up custom advanced segments for each domain, you could view 4 of these simultaneously in the standard reporting interface.

Answer (score 1):

Now, on the very first page of your Analytics account (Account Home), somewhere in upper-left corner, there is a button "Show Visits (last 30 days)" that does exactly what I personally need for a quick check - displays visits and change +/- behind every domain.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I'm aware you can't, you'd need to download the relevant data and crunch it manually.

You can, however, [structure in a rollup account to generate reports](http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/advanced-structure-your-account-with.html) for the future:-

> No need to panic. This post aims to offer an approach to help you plan
>   your Google Analytics accounts setup in a structured fashion to help
>   with clarity. I hope that by following the approach and the technical
>   steps, you will be able to collect and manage all your data, make more
>   sense of it, and most importantly, ensure what you are reporting on,
>   trending, dashboarding and analyzing is based on accurate data.

Some further reading is available in [google groups](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/JesBd6b4NJ8)