# Combine totals from two Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have multiple websites in Google Analytics. I can see a summary from the home dashboard of each site. How can I combine the count from each site, so I can see how many views, unique visitors, etc, across all sites.

More info: all sites are independent of each other, but are from the same company, we want to know (at a glance, without getting a calculator out) how many visits and visitors we are getting across all sites.

Answer (score 2):

See my answer on a similar question here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/38395/10527

> This document describes a variety of ways to collect visits to
>   multiple domains in a single view (profile)—as if they were a single
>   site rather than two separate ones. It also covers how to track
>   portions of a website, such as sub-directories and iFramed content. If
>   you are unfamiliar with the general process of cross-domain tracking,
>   see Domains and Directories in our Help Center.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you are using older ga.js code or the new universal analytics (analytics.js).In the older code you can send data to 2 or more profiles simultaneously using this method:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-12345-6']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker',true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['ua2._setAccount','UA-34567-1']);
_gaq.push(['ua2._setAllowLinker',true]);
_gaq.push(['ua2._trackPageview']);
```

You can use the 12345-X UA codes for any individual site and have their own isolated data and use the 34567-1 code as a master code shared by all of your sites. Please note that if you wish to track traffic between the sites using the same UTM cookies you have to implement cross domain tracking.

If you are using universal analytics then you can use multiple trackers out of the box:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers

Comment: Good solution, but this would only work for future stats gathered, ideally I could see 'back in time'.

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible unless you are using the same UA number for all sites. Another possible solution is using the same UA number for all sites and applying a full URL filter, which will enable you to segment the data by domain URL, but this solution won't include past data either.